# Problem with conditional statement observing checkmarks in tableview

Tags: json, swift, tableview

I have a table that is looking at JSON data and presenting it in a tableView. When a user selects a row a checkmark appears, When a button is pressed I would like to present an alert if the entire table has no checkmarks or do `print("Some Rows are Selected")`

I have tried the following, but it just always shows the alert if a checkmark is in a table or not:

```
    guard let selectedIndexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows, !selectedIndexPaths.isEmpty else {
        //Show Alert here...
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Select a Row", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }
    print("Some Rows are Selected")
}
```

When decoding I also mention: struct Structure: Decodable {

```
let animal: String
let food: String

var Selected : Bool {

}
```

Comment: Do you have special code in didSelectRow? Also, since you have a custom struct which has the selected, what about reading it? `guard yourArrayOfStructure.contains(where: { $0.Selected == true }) else { //show alert }`?

Comment: Yes your comment is exactly what I am looking for, but I would also like to execute a function if `selected == true` and if false show an alert, how do I modify the first part to also execute the function testMode()?